# Dynamodb connection timeout inside lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda function that executes every 30 seconds (step function make 2 lambda calls with 30 sec timeout every minute). It **reads** some data (about 90 items) from dynamodb. And sometimes it throws me `ConnectTimeoutError` and I can't udenrstand why (today lambda was throwing me this errors for 3 hours every 30 seconds and than it start work correctly again)

Table have `On demand` capacity. Lambda runtime: python3.8

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: @MarkB Yes, It runs in a VPC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the VPC subnets you have your Lambda function configured to use either don't have a route to a NAT Gateway, or a route to a [DynamoDB VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html). Each subnet it runs in will need one of those two routes defined.

Note that if the Lambda function doesn't actually need to access anything in the VPC, it would work better without the VPC configuration.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, `ConnectionTimeout` to dynamodb is gone. But now, for some reason starts fails (not very frequently) requests to another web resource (not aws related), but maybe problems on their side

Comment: If it's running in a VPC, and also needs access to external resources on the Internet, make sure the Lambda function is ONLY deploying in subnets with a route to a NAT Gateway.